# Can you list virtual hardware of a guest via the CLI in ESXi 5.0?

Tags: vmware-esxi, command-line-interface, hardware, guest

Can any one tell me of an ESXi line command that can be used to list the different virtual hardware components assigned to VMWare guests running on ESXi, with vcenter?

E.g. I want to find out how many of our guests are running with the e1000 network adaptor or how many have 2 sockets and 2 cores.

I'd like to do this in ESXi/vSphere not in the guest OS.

Comment: You can certainly do this from the VMware vSphere client.

Comment: If you mean the GUI client, then I already know about that. If you mean from a CLI (command line interface) then I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: The VMware vSphere client is the GUI client, so that is what I meant. I wasn't sure if you knew that you could get the info there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerCLI, the number of CPUs is accessible directly as a property of the VirtualMachine object returned by `Get-VM`, but in v5.0, the other virtual hardware objects have their own cmdlets, e.g. `Get-HardDisk`, `Get-NetworkAdapter`.  So you'd have to do something like:

```
    Get-VM | ForEach-Object {$nic = Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $_; Write-Host "$_.Name $nic.Type"}
```